# Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory upon doing lookup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi

I am trying to get this standalone (no server involved) JNDI InitialContext lookup to   work.  I am getting this exception:

**Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory**

```
try {  
    Hashtable <String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();   
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");  
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"localhost:1099");  
    env.put("java:comp/env/jms/RNCQueueConnectionFactory", 
            "javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory");  
    env.put("Big", "Data");  
    Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);  
    jndiContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/RNCQueueConnectionFactory");  
    testval = (String) jndiContext.lookup("Big");
} catch (NamingException ne) {  
    System.out.println(ne.getMessage());  
}
```

To me and from what I have read, I probably did not set up my context correctly.  Has   anyone successfully set up a standalone JNDI?

Comment: think you might be missing a jar. why are you using 'com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory'?

Comment: I saw it in a code example on a related web page.  I thought it might be a that could be used in a standalone JNDI lookup situation.  I thought I would give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I am working with a Maven project and I just added the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-naming</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

JNDI is an API to access naming and directory services. There's [The JNDI Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/) that should let you get up to speed with the API and how it works.

As an API, JNDI needs an implementation to work. In your particular case, you need to find the jar with the class `com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory`. Once you've figured out what jar it should be, you will need to add it to `CLASSPATH` and re-run the application.

It might not be all you need to access the JNDI service, but at least will get you past the initial error. Please consult the article and [The JNDI Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/).

Comment: Good morning Jacek, Thank you for responding to my question.  Yesterday after I posted I read the tutorial you mention.  After some investigation I used com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory.  It is define in the jar file, fscontext.jar.  This may require that I put the properties in a file.  However, I am now finding the method in the jar.  I have modified my code a bit.  It now looks like this:

Comment: Jacek,After some investigation in the tutorial on JNDI, I used com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory.I have modified my code a bit.  
try {
   Hashtable <String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"); 
    env.put("java:comp/env/jms/RNCQueueConnectionFactory", "javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory");
    env.put("Fish", "AndChips");
    Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);
    testval = (String) jndiContext.lookup("Fish"); 
}
catch (NamingException ne) {  
    ne.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Fish
atcom.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.getObjectFromBindings(RefFSContext.java:400)
atcom.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookupObject(RefFSContext.java:327)
at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at gov.hhs.cms.rnc.SampleRNCTest2.testRNC(SampleRNCTest2.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.Delegatin

Comment: Above is the stack trace, @Jacek Laskowski

Comment: The lines `env.put("java:comp/env/jms/RNCQueueConnectionFactory", "javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory")` and `env.put("Fish", "AndChips")` don't do much and should be removed. They don't participate in setting up the JNDI bindings. I don't know how you should work with RefFSContextFactory and whether or not it allows to bind new values to the tree. Consult the documentation.